# Solving $y(2x+y)dx+(3x^2+4xy-y)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following ODE, using substitution method.

$y(2x+y)dx+(3x^2+4xy-y)dy=0$

> Substitution Method is used when you have an ODE of the form
>
> $p(x,y)\ dx + q(x,y) \ dy = 0$
>
> where $\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}\ne \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}$, so the equation is not exact. But it might be exact when we multiply it by an integrating factor $u(x)=e^{\int f(x) dx}$, where $f(x)=\frac{1}{q}(\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial q}{\partial x})$.

Here is what I have so far,

$p(x,y)=y(2x+y)$, $q(x,y)=3x^2+4xy-y$

$2x+2y=\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}\ne \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}=6x+4y$

So it is not exact.

The point I am stuck at is that $\frac{1}{q}(\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial q}{\partial x})=\frac{1}{3x^2+4xy-y}(-4x-2y)$, shouldn't $f$ be a function in the variable $x$ only?

**Edit:**
After some research, I found out that there are 3 cases:

1- $u$ could be a function in $x$ only.

2- $u$ could be a function in $y$ only.

3- $u$ could be a function in both $x$ and $y$, and in this case it will be a PDE instead.

Now, I was given this question in an intro to ODEs class, so I am assuming that there is a way I could use to turn my equation into an ODE? or is there a mistake in my solution in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that, this is non homogeneous ordinary differential equation,
$$y(2x+y)dx+(3x^2+4xy-y)dy=0$$
Equation of the type $Mdx +Ndy =0$ (exact differential equation)

$$ \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} = 2x + 2y $$

$$\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} = 6x +4y $$

Notice that $$ \frac{\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y}}{M} = \frac{4x +2y}{y(2x+y)} = 2/y $$

Which is a function of $y$ only

So, Integrating factor is $$ e^{\int(2/y)dy } = e^{2 \log y } = y² $$
Multiply this integrating factor with the equation you have and it will reduce to a exact differential equation.

$$y^3(2x+y)dx+y²(3x^2+4xy-y)dy=0$$

You can now find the solution for it by using;

$$ \int _{ \text{taking y as constant}}Mdx + \int_{\text{terms containing y only}} Ndy = C$$

Where $C$ is the intergation constant.

Answer (score 1):

In such problems it can be useful to try to find the multiplier in the following form:
$$\mu(x,y)=x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}$$
So we have:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left[x^{\alpha}y^{\beta+1}(2x+y)\right]=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}(3x^2+4xy-y)\right]$$
$$x^\alpha y^\beta((\beta+1)(2x+y)+y)=
x^{\alpha-1}y^{\beta}(\alpha(3x^2+4xy-y)+x(6x+4y))$$
$$x(\beta+1)(2x+y)+xy=3\alpha x^2+4\alpha xy-\alpha y+6x^2+4xy$$
Let $\alpha=0$:
$$2\beta x^2+\beta xy+2x^2=6x^2+2xy$$
$$(2\beta-4)x^2+(\beta-2)xy=0$$
And $\beta=2$. We get the needed equality. Now let's use $\mu(x,y)=y^{2}$ function:
$$y^2\cdot y(2x+y)dx+y^2\cdot(3x^2+4xy-y)dy=0$$
$$2xy^3dx+y^4dx+3x^2y^2dy+4xy^3dy-y^3dy=0$$
$$y^3d(x^2)+y^4dx+x^2d(y^3)+xd(y^4)+d\left(-\frac{y^4}{4}\right)=0$$
$$d(x^2y^3)+d(xy^4)+d\left(-\frac{y^4}{4}\right)=0$$
$$4x^2y^3+4xy^4-y^4=C$$